# suitescript 2.0 : How to modify and save subrecord in clientscript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to modify and save `subrecord` in clientscript, but when it is saved, I get the following error:

> "Cannot read property 'invalidateCurrentSublistLineForSubrecordCache' of undefined"

**Current code:**

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NModuleScope public
*/
define(['N/record','N/currentRecord','N/search'],
  function(record,currentRecord,search) {
  return({
    stock: function(context) {
      var curRec = currentRecord.get();

      var ab_search = search.create({
        type: search.Type.TRANSACTION,
        title: 'YXZC_Assembly_Build_Search',
        id: 'customsearch_yxzc_assembly_build_search',
        columns: ['internalid'],
        filters: [
          ['createdfrom', 'is', curRec.id],'and',['type','is','Build']
        ]
      });
      ab_search.save();
      var searchResult = ab_search.run().getRange({
        start: 0,
        end: 1
      })[0];
      var internalid = searchResult.getValue(searchResult.columns[0]);
      search.delete({
        id: 'customsearch_yxzc_assembly_build_search'
      });
      var rec = record.load({
        type: record.Type.ASSEMBLY_BUILD,
        id: internalid,
        // isDynamic: true,
      });
      var inventorydetailRec = rec.getSubrecord({
        fieldId: 'inventorydetail',
      });
      var line = inventorydetailRec.getLineCount({
        sublistId: 'inventoryassignment'
      });
      for (var i=0; i<line; i++){
        inventorydetailRec.setSublistValue({
          sublistId:'inventoryassignment',
          fieldId: 'inventorystatus',
          line: i,
          value: '2'
        });
      };
      var recId = rec.save({
        enableSourcing: true,
        ignoreMandatoryFields: true
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I am not sure what `invalidateCurrentSublistLineForSubrecordCache` property means.

**What does anyone know about why this error is occurring?**

Comment: Is `inventorystatus` a valid fieldId? I'm not seeing that as an option under the inventoryassignment sublist.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `record.submitFields()`

See https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4267283788.html

I have just stumbled upon your question since I had the same issue but found a solution by the help of @erictgrubaugh

Answer (score 0):

Subrecords are read-only for client scripts. Clients scripts are able to delete a subrecord from a parent record, but they can not modify them. See Supported Deployments for Subrecord Scripting [in the NetSuite help](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4712495741.html)